# How shall i convince user to select multiple email-id?

Tags: usability, gui-design, interaction-design

I am inviting people to participate in my activity. I entered the email id. It got added into the list. Now shall i select multiple? (Is the question faced by many users)
What shall i do:
-Provide a label
-Message box
-Or something else
How shall i convince user?
How shall i make it easy?

[image]

Comment: To clarify, after adding one or more email addresses to the list (the "directory"), the user must then select one or more of those addresses and press the 'Invite' button in order to send the invitations? Is that correct?

Comment: @Matt Obee yes it goes in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

I think Basecamp do it well by presenting multiple inputs, seems like a simple way to indicate what's required:

[image]